# How to add a module dependency while building an AAR

Tags: android, android-library, aar, android-module

I created one library project with two modules. I added the 2nd module in the dependencies of the first module like this:

```
    implementation project(":module2")
```

I am able to generate the AAR file after this. But I'm getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

while running the client app.

Kindly help me find out what I am missing here.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError means that during compilation this class was presented but now (in runtime) it is absent. Maybe ProGuard/R8 obfuscation/shrink optimization has removed it. Are you sure that "NoClassDefFoundError" refers to one class included in ":module2"?

Comment: Yes it refers to one class of "module2"

Comment: If ":module2" it's yours and you've all it's source code: don't shrink/optimize/obfuscate it (without declaring relative rules in Proguard file) or who "imports" it could not have all methods/classes

Answer (score 0):

- In your first module build.gradle file, you can include like ,

  api project(":module2")